# Why there is only 8 peers in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, peers

I set `maxconnections=125` in `bitcoin.conf` but still has only 8 connections in nodelist. Please tell why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if port `8333` is open. If port is closed from internet, bitcoin client will make only 8 outgoing connections. `maxconnections` parameter works only for incoming connections.